# Why is two separate pointers pointing to two different memory locations(with different content) pass as equal in equality test?

Tags: string, token

I have a string, which is pointed to by a pointer char *filename. I want to see if a string in a directory is exactly the same as the one *filename is pointing to.
To achieve this, I wrote the whole directory (which is just lines of strings) into a text file tmp.txt and begin reading the text file line by line. For each line, I split the strings into tokens using delimiters(" \n\r") so that I can check the each token against the string char *filename is pointing to.

Here is the code:

```
    // DISECT EACH LINE, DELIMIT BY " "
    char *tok;
    char *ch = " \n\r";
    tok = strtok(temp_buffer, ch);
    while (tok != NULL)
    {
        printf ("filname: %s %d token: %s %d\n", filename, strlen(filename), tok, strlen(tok));
        if (*filename == *tok) 
        {
            printf ("this one\n");
            printf ("filname: %s  token: %s\n", filename, tok); 
        }
        tok = strtok(NULL, ch);
    }

}
fclose(fin);
```

The string *filename is pointing to is " trial.txt", and the printed directory(in the tmp.txt file) does have a token "trial.txt" as well. My assumption was that the if statement should only run once when the content of *filename is equal to the content of *tok, which is when they both have "trial.txt". However, the if statement also ran when *tok was pointing to another token "tmp.txt". Can someone explain how this is possible?

Comment: `*filename == *tok`  is just comparing the first character of the two strings.  Comparing the entire strings needs a library function such as `strcmp()`.

Comment: Oh man thanks. I've been breaking my head on this one without thinking outside of it. Cheers